# OracleDataReader returns only one row

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle

I'm trying to loop through a cursor. When I execute the command (denoted as sql - see below) directly in pl/sql I'm getting result set with more rows. 
But when I run this code, I'm getting only one row:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "select close, ts from dpr@price where qot_id=2029543939 and ts>='" + start + "' and  ts<='" + end + "'";
    using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        using (OracleDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
             while (rdr.Read())
             {                                
                  Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetOracleDecimal(0));
             }

         }
     }
}
```

The code doesn't throw any exception(at least not in an usual way; I mean it doesn't stop or writes stack trace). However I can see these lines by reader Object while debugging(I don't really think it is relevant here, but showing the output "just in case"):

```
InitialLONGFetchSize = 'rdr.InitialLONGFetchSize' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' 

InitialLOBFetchSize = 'rdr.InitialLOBFetchSize' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

The results should have only types `DateTime` and `Number (10,4)`. And the table has no fields with type lob or long.

This is the table scheme:

```
QOT_ID    NUMBER
TS            DATE
CLOSE     NUMBER
OPEN      NUMBER
HIGH      NUMBER
LOW       NUMBER
KASSE     NUMBER
VOLUME    NUMBER
CLOSE_BID     NUMBER
SPL_BEREINIGT VARCHAR2
OPEN_INTEREST NUMBER
TRADES    NUMBER
TURNOVER      NUMBER
HIGH_BID      NUMBER
LOW_ASK   NUMBER
```

The query is correct and the entries exist. The returned row seems to be random one... It is not the first or last row. I'm using ODT with ODAC 11. I have VS2012 and working under windows 7(32-bit). I'm connected to Oracle 10g .

Any clue what am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you verified the query by running it in sql*plus or something?

Comment: Yes, it works and returns more rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [Oracle Data Provider for .Net](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A96160_01/features.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/win.101/b10117/client002.htm) and [here to](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/OracleCommandClass.htm#BABEGDHA)

It seems that quite possibly the issue could be resolved by specifying either of the following: (failure to specify either of these causes issues with both InitialLONGFetchSize and InitialLOBFetchSize)

- primary key
- ROWID
- unique columns - (defined as a set of columns on which a unique constraint has been defined or a unique index has been created, where at least one of the columns in the set has a NOT NULL constraint defined on it)

Failing that specify values for both InitialLONGFetchSize and InitialLOBFetchSize.

Comment: Paul, thank you for feedback. This table has no fields with LOB or Long type.